# Logstash PostgreSQL Unable to Connect Database Error (Docker)

Tags: postgresql, docker, jdbc, logstash

Logstash(docker) unable to connect database.
Error => Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:message=>Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections., :exception=>Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError

logstash.conf file:

```
input{
jdbc {
  jdbc_driver_library => '/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/postgresql-42.5.0.jar'
  jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
  jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2022/testdb"
  jdbc_user => "postgres"
  jdbc_password => "12345"
  statement => "SELECT * FROM users"
  schedule => "* * * * *"
}
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
         hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
         index => "%{indexName}"
    }
}
```

logstash.yml file:

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
```

How can i connect to database?

Comment: In `jdbc_connection_string` you need to use the name of the database container.  `localhost` is the logstash container and isn't running a database.

Comment: i tried but give this error:Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:message=>"Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.", :exception=>Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError, :cause=>org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem as follows =>

1-)My postgreSQL port is "2022" so i changed IPV4 port=127.0.0.1/22 in pg_hba.conf file.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/22            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/22            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all md5
```

2-) Use computer ip address(ipconfig) instead of localhost=

```
old= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2022/testdb 
new= jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.83:2022/testdb
```